# Prevent javascript gc while doing animation

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, garbage-collection

I will load a list of local files via javascript and perform css animation at the same time.

Loading those files causes GC and the frame rate drops seriously.
I know the gc is required. So I can design a time window without any animation.
But is there any way to suggest or ask system to do GC?

**Update**

I use this code to load preview files.

```
reader = new FileReader(); 
reader.onload = function(){blah}; 
// gc happens here reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

And the animation is just some regular transition-based css animation.

Comment: There is no way to explicitly ask the browser to collect garbage. Do you have some code that shows your problem?

Comment: I use this code to load preview files.  
    reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = function(){blah};  // gc happens here  
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
And the animation is just some regular transition-based css animation.

Comment: I haven't tried reproducing your problem. But if some labor intensive work is interfering with the rendering speed of your pages, you should in general consider offloading that work to a web worker. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: Workers look great. I calculate md5 of the loaded file. Maybe I can move all the loading and calculation to background. I'll try this idea asap. Hoping background worker won't cause the GC problem. Really appreciate your help.:D

Comment: I've tried it. It works very well and requires nearly no modification.  Thanks again:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to explicitly ask the browser to collect garbage.

If some labor intensive work is interfering with the rendering speed of your pages, you should in general consider offloading that work to a web worker.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers